# YAML: how to interpret sequence of mappings

Tags: python, yaml

On page 8 of the [YAML spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.pdf), the authors provide an example of page 4's "sequence of mappings" like this:

```
product:
    - sku         : BL394D
      quantity    : 4
      description : Basketball
      price       : 450.00
    - sku         : BL4438H
      quantity    : 1
      description : Super Hoop
      price       : 2392.00
```

For my own understanding how would I (roughly) represent that in, say, Python?

Mapping > Sequence > Mapping, Mapping, Mapping ... ?

```
{"Product" : ({ "sku" : "BL394D" }, {"quantity" : 4 }), ... }
```

Or Mapping > Sequence of mapping 1, 2, 3, ... ?

```
{"Product" : ({ "sku" : "BL394D" }), ({ "quantity" : 4 }), ... )}
```

Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for how to get the Python object from a yaml representation, you can use a yaml parser. Such as [pyyaml](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml).

Install with pip: `pip install pyyaml`

Then, for example:

```
>>> doc = """
    product:
         - sku         : BL394D
           quantity    : 4
           description : Basketball
           price       : 450.00
         - sku         : BL4438H
           quantity    : 1
           description : Super Hoop
           price       : 2392.00
     """

>>> yaml.load(doc)

{
    'product': [{
        'description': 'Basketball',
        'price': 450.0,
        'quantity': 4,
        'sku': 'BL394D'
    }, {
        'description': 'Super Hoop',
        'price': 2392.0,
        'quantity': 1,
        'sku': 'BL4438H'
    }]
}
```

Comment: PyYAML only supports most of  the YAML 1.1 spec (from 2005) which was replaced in 2009 by YAML 1.2. Apart from that `yaml.load()` is documented to be unsafe, and there is absolutely no reason not to use `yaml.safe_load()` if you insist on using PyYAML.

Answer (score 4):

It would appear as so in JSON:

```
{
    "product": [
        {
            "sku": "BL394D",
            "quantity": 4,
            "description": "Basketball",
            "price": 450
        },
        {
            "sku": "BL4438H",
            "quantity": 1,
            "description": "Super Hoop",
            "price": 2392
        }
    ]
}
```

So in Python, it would be an object that has a map to product, which is an array of other objects with the properties sku, quantity, etc.

Answer (score 3):

At the root of the YAML document there is a mapping. This has one key `product`. Its value is a sequence, with two items (indicated by the dashes `-`).

The sequence elements are again mappings, and the first key/value pair of each of these mappings starts on the same line as the sequence element (its key is `sku`).

In Python, by default, a mapping is loaded as a `dict` and a sequence is loaded as a `list`, so you could define the data in Python using:

```
dict(product=[dict(
  sku='BL394D', quantity= 4, description='Basketball', price=450.00),
  dict(sku='BL4438H', quantity= 1, description='Super Hoop', price=2392.00),
])
```

You can of course just load the data structure and then print that to see how this is loaded.